# Перезапись массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Собственно вопрос такой. Как можно перезаписать массивы в js? Тоесть, к примеру я пишу игру шашки, у меня есть переменная, которая указывает каким цветом играет текущий игрок. Поле нужно сгенерировать таким образом, что бы не в зависимости от цвета шашки текущего игрока были внизу.

Игра онлайн связка node.js и тп.

```
    /**
    *  Расставляем шашки (в начале игры )
    */
    draughts: function() 
    {

        // координаты белых шашек 
        var ch_white = ["5.0","5.2","5.4","5.6",

                        "6.1","6.3","6.5","6.7",

                        "7.0","7.2","7.4","7.6",];

        // координаты черных шашек 
        var ch_black = ["0.1","0.3","0.5","0.7",

                        "1.0","1.2","1.4","1.6",

                        "2.1","2.3","2.5","2.7",];

        // расставляем все белые шашки
        ch_white.forEach(function(coord) 
        {
            $('[data-coord="'+coord+'"]').html('<div class="checker ck_white" data-checker="white" data-coord="'+coord+'"></div>')
        });

        // расставляем все черные шашки
        ch_black.forEach(function(coord) 
        {
            $('[data-coord="'+coord+'"]').html('<div class="checker ck_black" data-checker="black" data-coord="'+coord+'"></div>')
        });
    },
```

И тут есть некая переменная player, которая равна либо balck либо white. Сейчас ch_white всегда будут внизу.

Задача состоит в том, что если player=='black', нужно массивы поменять местами:

```
        // координаты черных шашек 
        var ch_black = ["5.0","5.2","5.4","5.6",

                        "6.1","6.3","6.5","6.7",

                        "7.0","7.2","7.4","7.6",];

        // координаты белых  шашек 
        var ch_white = ["0.1","0.3","0.5","0.7",

                        "1.0","1.2","1.4","1.6",

                        "2.1","2.3","2.5","2.7",];
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это быстренько реализовать по красоте

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Этим вы и обозначите, что вопрос решен.  
Если сами нашли решение - напишите свой ответ и отметьте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняйте в переменных указатель на нужный массив в памяти, используя промежуточную переменную.

```
var buf = ch_black;
ch_black = ch_white;
ch_white = buf;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже так думал, но в вдруг был бы еще вариант. Вопрос снимаю, понял, что это говнокод и оптимизировал.